# Azure function freezes

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have 15 azure functions in one project.
I noticied that 2 of them freeze in azure cloud. Functions should be triggered by timer `"schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"` every minute, but from what i see in azure they called more rarely. I tried to change scedule, but the problem still exists. What could be the reason of this freez?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The trigger only happen if there's not a previous execution running. So that could be the reason, your function is taking more than one minute to complete. More info about it:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/84

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But usually funnction runing time is 1,5 sec - 20 sec. I don't think it can be run for more than 1 minute.

Comment: are you sure this is the only time triggered function in the function app?

Answer (score 1):

Change your CRON expression to "0 * * * * *" for the function to be triggered every minute.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions use NCRON not CRON .

Your expression is [designed to run every hour's first minute](https://ncrontab.swimburger.net/?expression=0%201%20*%20*%20*%20*) not every minute. I'm not sure how it's running at the times you show in the screen shot, but sounds impossible and would guess the screen shot and ncron expression are not from same function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was in awaiting context async operation.
I added `configureAwait(false)` to all async calls, and it started to work correctly.[image]

I was surprissed, because i thought `configureAwait(false)` was relavant only in ASP.NET applications